# A method for holding down a keyboard key for a long period of time

Tags: gaming, pc, keyboards, mice

### Problem

I play Path of Exile and other games like it. In it, you point your mouse at a specific location and click to move your character there. You can hold the button down to constantly move your character in a particular direction.

Holding down the move button for a long time really puts strain on my fingers. Unlike a game like World of Warcraft where you might use an "auto run" button to travel across long distances, I need to be able to quickly start and stop movement to respond to surroundings.

**I am looking for a way to easily hold down a single key for a long period of time, occasionally be able to interrupt it quickly, while also having access to a dozen other buttons for other important keys.**

### Attempted Solutions

##### Use a keyboard key and mouse button

My first solution was to simply rebind the "mouse click" action to also be usable on my keyboard. The game uses QWER-like keybindings. I rebound the R key so that I could alternate between mouse clicks and pressing a key with my left hand. This helps a little but ultimately it just wears out my left and right index fingers.

##### Use a foot pedal

I purchased a USB foot pedal to use. It felt a little awkward and the software for the one I bought had a memory leak that causes it to crash over and over. I gave up on this pretty quickly but would be open to revisiting it.

##### [Azeron Cyborg](https://store.azeron.eu)

I purchased an Azeron Cyborg controller. I really like using it. My other fingers feel pretty good and I don't have a lot of wrist pain. I moved movement onto the thumb switch on the side. I just hold that thing down when I want to move around. The game does not support using the analog stick to move so this was the best compromise. However, this has introduced some new problems:

- the switch maybe wasn't designed to be held down? sometimes it just doesn't work. the azeron software detects that it's pressed but it's not sending a signal to the game.
- now my thumb hurts! the switch is fairly resistive so I think I'm straining my thumb to keep it engaged

##### AutoHotKey toggle

PoE expressly states that using key macros like AutoHotKey is not permitted by the terms of service. How much they can enforce that... I don't know. But also using a toggle might be a little awkward to play with. I might be able to learn to live with it though.

### Proposed Solutions

- Capacitive thumb button? - I think I'm looking for something with a capacitive switch that I can cover up with my thumb when I want to move and uncover when I want to stop. I don't want to press something down
- A different gaming keypad? - I see gaming keypads that have thumb switches kinda like the azeron has. Maybe those ones have better thumb buttons for what I want to do?
- Another hands-free input? - I don't know what it would be, but if there was something I could use that didn't require a finger to actuate, that would be neat!